# How to stop or wait accessing function by newly created process while the same function is currently being access by current process in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading

processingP = mp.Process(target=a_process, args=(processCollection,mongoIP, mongoPort))
processingP.start()

def createSigneIndexForCollection(mongoDatabase, collectionName, columnName):
    rawlogCollection = mongoDatabase[collectionName]
    rawlogCollection.create_index([(columnName , 1)])

def createIndexForCollection(mongoDatabase, collectionName):
    columnsToBeIndexed = ["Name", "Message",etc.]
    for columnName in columnsToBeIndexed:
        indexThread = threading.Thread(target=createSigneIndexForCollection, args=(mongoDatabase, collectionName, columnName))
        indexThread.start()
        indexThread.join()

def a_process(processCollection, mongoIP, mongoPort):
    
    mongoDatabase = getDatabase(mongoIP, mongoPort, mongoDatabase)
    
    createIndexForCollection(mongoDatabase, processCollection)
     
    if processCollection != "NULL":
        ScanningThread = threading.Thread(target=check, args=(mongoDatabase, processCollection))
        ScanningThread .start()
        ScanningThread .join()
```

In above code snippet, each process will start after every 6 min. And each process will access **createIndexForCollection** function and go to the next line. But I do not want newly created process to access **createIndexForCollection** function while it is being access by current process. Once execution of current process finished on **createIndexForCollection** function then only next process should access the **createIndexForCollection** function.

Comment: show more context where the current process calls `createIndexForCollection`

Comment: with `current process` you mean some previous `mp.Process` or the main python script process?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest previous process

Comment: in terms of design: that eliminates a feasibility of parallel processes as each next process should be blocked and wait until the previous process ends its inner routine. That does not justify applying of multiple parallel processes

Answer (score 0):

You can use a token shared across processes and a condition variable to serialize the processes, like this:

```py
import time
import multiprocessing as mp

def worker(index: int, token, cv):
    with cv:
        if index > 0 and index != token.value:
            cv.wait_for(lambda : index == token.value)
        print(f'worker {index}, token: {token.value}')
        token.value += 1
        cv.notify_all()

def main():
    cv = mp.Condition()
    token = mp.Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    procs = []
    for idx in range(10):
        p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(idx, token, cv))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)
        # time.sleep(0.01)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Result:

```bash
$ python3 b.py                   
worker 0, token: 0
worker 1, token: 1
worker 2, token: 2
worker 3, token: 3
worker 4, token: 4
worker 5, token: 5
worker 6, token: 6
worker 7, token: 7
worker 8, token: 8
worker 9, token: 9
```

Good luck!